# Single Page Application with signalR: performance testing

Tags: signalr, single-page-application, performance-testing

I have an issue to evaluate the amount of concurrent users that our website can handle. Website is a Single Page Application built on .net framework with Durandal.js on the frontend. We use signalR (hubs) for real time communication between server and client.

The only option I see is ‘browser testing’, so each test should run browser instance (or use phantomJs etc) to keep real time connection with the server (as in real usage). Are there any other options to do this except use tests that will use browser instance to emulate user’s behaviour? What is the best way to emulate load of e.g. 1000 concurrent users?

I’ve found several cloud services that support such load testing, e.g. loadimpact, blazemeter. Would be great if someone can share their experience of using such tools.

Answer (score 1):

SignalR provides tool called Crank, which can be used to test how many connections can be handled by given machine.

More info: http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/performance/signalr-connection-density-testing-with-crank

Comment: I need to test whole application, not only signalR part.

Comment: Did you get a chance to evaluate https://www.visualstudio.com/features/vso-cloud-load-testing-vs . Recommending this as it looks you are using VS for your development work and would be familiar with Load Testing solution in VS (Ultimate)

Answer (score 0):

Make your own script to create virtual users! that is the most effective way to recreate real world load/stress! use Akka Actor model(for creating virtual users) with java signalr client! (if you want you can use Gatling tool as framework and attach your script written in java or scala to virtual users of Gatling!)
make script dynamic by storing user info(Authentication token or user credentials) in xml document.

Please comment questions I can guide you end to end as I completed building+deploying such tool...

Comment: Hi jaydeep - do you have a sample for this approach which you can share with me?